# Same dates (but different entry ID) counted twice when using SUM

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to make a database, where employees can register when they were, and for how much time they worked during that day.

By the end of each month, I should be able to extract the total of hours per employee, the total of hours that should be paid (there are different applicable rates - for example, if one worked from 5:30 to 7:00, they were working for 1,5 hours, but they will be paid for 3 hours of work).

So, when I try to get these hours per day, I have no problem whatsoever :

```
idemployee  idhours_count   date        total   total_to_pay
1           1               2015-05-21  6.5000  8.350000
1           2               2015-05-22  7.9167  14.083333
1           3               2015-05-23  10.0833 17.645833
3           4               2015-05-26  5.0000  5.000000
3           5               2015-06-06  11.8333 20.850000
3           6               2015-06-06  8.6667  8.750000
```

Why are there 2 entries on 2015-05-22 for employee 1 ? Well, he may have done 2 shifts during the day. *Not that we tortured him to do that, but well.*

The total is calculated in a view, *hours_summary2*, where there is the detail of the hours (hours on shift 1, hours on shift 2, etc.), and the total to pay is calculated in a different view,*, where all the rates are defined as well.

Anyway, in order to have the monthly result, I created a last view, which gives also the hours detail from the view I mentioned. The code looks like that :

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = root@localhost 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW payment_summary AS
    SELECT 
        hours_to_pay.idemployee AS idemployee,
        MONTH(hours_to_pay.date) AS month,
        YEAR(hours_to_pay.date) AS year,
        TRUNCATE(SUM(hours_to_pay.total), 2) AS Number_hours,
        TRUNCATE(SUM(hours_to_pay.total_to_pay),
            2) AS Number_hours_to_pay,
        /* Code for the detail of the hours */
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.ew_es) AS early_week_early_start,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.early_week_normal) AS early_week_normal,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.wednesday_overtime) AS wednesday_overtime,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.ew_es_h) AS early_week_early_start_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.early_week_holiday) AS early_week_whole_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.wednesday_overtime_h) AS wednesday_overtime_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.late_week_normal) AS late_week_normal,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.lw_le) AS late_week_late_end,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.late_week_holiday) AS late_week_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.lw_le_h) AS late_week_late_end_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sat_normal) AS sat_normal,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sat_overtime) AS sat_overtime,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sat_holiday) AS sat_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sat_overtime_h) AS sat_overtime_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sun_normal) AS sun_normal,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sun_overtime) AS sun_overtime,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sun_holiday) AS sun_holiday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.sun_overtime_h) AS sun_overtime_h,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.travel_time_1) AS travel_time_1,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.travel_time_2) AS travel_time_2,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.excess_hour_weekday) AS excess_hour_weekday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.excess_hour_saturday) AS excess_hour_saturday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.excess_hour_sunday) AS excess_hour_sunday,
        SUM(hours_calc_summary.excess_hour_holiday) AS excess_hour_holiday
    FROM
        (hours_calc_summary
        JOIN hours_to_pay)
    WHERE
        ((hours_calc_summary.idemployee = hours_to_pay.idemployee)
            AND (hours_calc_summary.date = hours_to_pay.date))
    GROUP BY hours_to_pay.idemployee , month , year
```

(The *hours_to_pay.date* call works if I put date between quotes, I removed them for the sake of formatting here)

So now, if I were to do the calculations manually :

- Employee 1 worked for 24.5 hours and will be paid 40.07 hours for May ;
- Employee 3 worked for 5 hours and will be paid 5 hours for May ;
- Employee 3 worked for 20.5 hours and will be paid 29.6 hours for June.

But, here are the results :

`idemployee month   year    number_hours    number_hours_to_pay
1   5   2015    24.50   40.07
3   5   2015    5.00    5.00
3   6   2015    41.00   72.28`

Employee 3 on June has more hours !

After doing some trial and error, it looks like reporting hours on the same date gives some funky results, because they are counted twice each. So the view thinks there are 4 entries for June for employee 3 while there are only 2 entries.

So I am wondering, what's wrong with my code ? I tried to change the GROUP BY conditions, but no cigar (or no clue whatsoever) :  grouping by month should've been enough in my opinion, while grouping by day would not report the hours per month.

*Also taking suggestions for a more relevant title.*

Comment: Was a bit too fast when setting up the tags. Thanks for noticing !

Comment: @OP: `'JOIN hours_to_pay'` ***ON*** *what* ???

Comment: Yeah, I struggle also a lot with that one. It's MySQL Workbench's doing : it automatically transforms "*from hours_calc_summary, hours_to_pay*" into an empty JOIN clause when I create the view. And honest to God I don't know how to bypass that. I doubt it's where the thing goes wrong though : I tried to completely rewrite my WHERE clauses into a JOIN, and nothing changed.